# Find determinant of $B=(A_1+A_{n-1}|A_2+A_{n}|A_3+A_1|A_4+A_2|...|A_n+A_{n-2})$ given $\det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We have matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which we can write in columns form $A = (A_1|A_2|...|A_n)$, where $A_i$ is a column $i$.

Now, we make cyclic shift with a step 2 and add that to the old matrix and get a new matrix:
$$B=(A_1+A_{n-1}|A_2+A_{n}|A_3+A_1|A_4+A_2|...|A_n+A_{n-2})$$

The task is to express $\det B$ in terms of $\det A$.

My attempt: I've tried to use linearity of determinant and decompose $\det B$ into $2^n$ terms. I know that a lot of the terms will be zero due to them having same columns, other non-zero terms are specific permutations which can be returned to $\det A$ by switching columns. But there are a lot of them and each one has it's own number of column shifts to return to $A$. So I am stuck here

Comment: Your solution sounds like it is going in the right direction. I believe there are only two or four permutations you can get from those 2^n... say you pick a decomposition, and its first column has A1. Then there is only one A(n-1) left, in the second to last column, so your second to last column must be A(n-1). Then there is only one A(n-3)... if n is odd, this will completely determine the permutation. If n is even, you can independently set the second column to A2 or An.

Comment: @AndrewTindall, thanks, I'll try to dig that way further

Comment: @AndrewTindall I've sold this your way and got:  1) $0$ if $n$ is divisible by $4$ 2)$4\det A$ if $n$ is even but not divisible by $4$ 3)$2\det A$ if $n$ is odd


Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.* Write $B=AC$ for some [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $C$. As there is an explicit formula for the determinant of a circulant matrix, you may calculate $\det(B)$ from $\det(A)$ and $\det(C)$.

Comment: thanks, I will try that too

Answer (score 1):

There is a tricky way to get to the result, which is actually a bit articulated. Less tricky said, it is an elementary way to compute the determinant of the circulant matrix user1551 mentioned.
We firstly see three lemmas, increasingly related to the problem.

**Lemma 1.** Suppose $\omega$ is a primitive $k$-th root of unity. Then
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(1+\omega^i) = 1- (-1)^k$$

*Proof*. The solutions of the polynomial $x^k-1$ are the k-roots of unity, so that
$$ x^k-1 = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-\omega^i) $$
Substituting $x=-1$ we get the desired result.

**Lemma 2.** Let $S$ be the $n \times n$ matrix such that $A (x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_n, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1})$, i.e. the shift matrix. Then it is diagonalizable and its diagonal form is $\text{diag}(1, \omega, \ldots, \omega^{n-1})$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $n$ root of unity.

*Proof.* You can verify that the eigenvectors are $(1, \omega^j, \omega^{2j}, \ldots, \omega^{(k-1)j})$ for $j=0, \ldots, k-1$.

**Lemma 3.** Let $M$ be a matrix with diagonal form $D$. Then 
$$\det(1+M) =\det(1+D)$$

*Proof.* Indeed, let $B$ be such that $BMB^{-1} = D$. Multiplying $\det(1+M)$ by $\det(B), \det(B^{-1})$ we get
$$ \det( B(1+M)B^{-1}) = \det(1+BMB^{-1}) = \det(1+D)$$

Okay! Here we are. Now the problem is almost done.

Let $A=(A_1 | \ldots | A_n)$ be a matrix. Note that $(A_{n-1}, A_n, A_1, \ldots, A_{n-2})$ can be written as $AS^2$. Indeed, when we multiply the two matrices we can do it row by row of A, getting the rows shifted by two: on balance, we'll have shifted the columns of $A$ by two.

You asked to compute
$$\det(A+AS^2) = \det(A) \det(1+S^2)$$
By lemma 2, we know that the diagonal form of $S$ is $\text{diag}(1, \omega, \ldots, \omega^{n-1})$. Thus, the diagonal form of $S^2$ is $\text{diag}(1, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{2(n-1)})$. By Lemma 3, we are reduced to compute
$$ \det(1+\text{diag}(1, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{2(n-1)}))$$

Because the exponents has to be reduced modulo n, we have distinguish $n$ even or odd.

**Case 1**: *n odd*. Here the numbers $2k$ spans all the numbers from 0 to $n-1$ (try $n=5$ to believe), so we compute
$$ \det(1+\text{diag}(1, \omega, \ldots, \omega^{n-1})) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+\omega^k) = 1-(-1)^n = 2$$
By lemma 1 and n odd.

** Case 2**: *n even*. Set $n=2m$. Here the numbers $2k$ spans twice the even numbers $0, 2,\ldots, 2(m-1)$ (try $n=6$ to believe), so we compute
$$ \det(1+\text{diag}(1, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{2(m-1)},1, \omega^2, \ldots, \omega^{2(m-1)} )) = \left( \prod_{k=0}^{m-1}(1+(\omega^2)^k ) \right )^2 = (1-(-1)^m)^2 $$
Using the fact that $\omega^2$ is a primitive $m$-root of unity. We have two further cases: if $m$ is even the result is zero, otherwise is 4.

**Conclusion** On balance, the reuslt is the following (hard to guess a priori, in my opinion):

1. $2\det(A)$, if $n$ is odd;
2. $4\det(A)$, if $n$ is even but not multiple of four;
3. $0$, if $n$ is multiple of four.

You can have fun in computing the same thing for a general shift, depending on the gcd of the size and the shift (the same method applies!).

Comment: Thanks, not have read yet but I've got the same answer by using method in the comments